# Batch File to Automatically Install List of Drivers without User Interaction

Tags: windows, batch-file, installation, drivers, user-interaction

At work, one of the tasks I am responsible for is resetting computers to their factory settings and installing the updated drivers. Lenovo makes this easy with their System Update tool, but Dell and other companies require you to install drivers manually.

Because I am doing this process on so many machines, I am trying to find a way to automate the process so all I have to do is stick a USB in the machine, start a batch file, and let it go. Basically, I need a batch file that installs a bunch of drivers in a folder (that I download individually and put together first) without me needing to press "Ok" and "Next" for every single driver. I've tried a few things, but the /s or -s doesn't seem to be working. Does anybody have a workaround or know how to do this?

Here is the code that I have tried already:

```
pushd %~dp0
start /wait setup32.exe -s
echo press key when install finished!
pause
popd
```

Also tried:

```
@echo off
start /wait "" adobereader.exe /s /passive /quiet EULA_ACCEPT=YES
```

Nothing seems to work so far. For both of them, the driver installation starts, but it still requires user interactivity to continue the installation by pressing "Ok" and "Next".

Thank you for all of your help!

Comment: Why not build a standard image with all drivers already installed and sysprep it?  It saves a lot of time over deploying the vanilla OS with no updates or drivers installed, then updating each workstation individually.  I'm guessing Server Fault would be the best place to ask for more info.

Comment: That's the method that I originally used. I created a ghost image using Symantec's software and tried installing it on new machines. When booting though on the new machine, all I get is a black screen with a white blinking line on the top. Not sure why. Are there any other third party ghosting software you recommend?

Also, sometimes I'd get a single machine of a certain model, so an image wouldn't work. In that case i'd still have to install the drivers individually, which is why I still want a solution to this problem as well. Thanks!

Comment: The problem is that not all installers reliably support flags allowing unattended installation.  `msiexec`, for example, has a `/quiet` switch.  But Dell driver installers use self-extracting zip files, quite a different beast.  [sysprep](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/the-system-preparation-tool-sysprep-in-microsoft-windows-7) and GhostCast are really the most hands-off way of imaging machines.  If Ghost / GhostCast isn't working for you, you could try CloneZilla.  But really, this stuff is much better asked on Server Fault.

Comment: Does sysprep work in the same way that GhostCast does? I tried searching around, but I couldn't find a clear set way on how to create an image and deploy it on the new device.

Could you specify how to do it or provide some links?